# SUM IF FREQUENCY MATCH

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to add another criteria for the below formula. On the Payroll Data tab I have column H that has hours in it, some of those hours may be negative so I don't it to count those rows with negative numbers in the hours. I tried just add another if statement within the 2nd nested IF but that didn't work for me.

The formula looks for the Job ID which is in the A column, then it looks at the Trade which is in the J column. If the Emp ID for the Trade which is in the F column is unique it counts for each of the trades APP1 thru APP4. I also want it to look at the H column which is hours and if see a negative number do not count the Trade

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Payroll Data'!$A$2:$A$155=$A2,IF('Payroll Data'!$J$2:$J$155="APP1",IF('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155<>"",MATCH("~"&'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155,'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155&"",0)))),ROW('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155)-ROW('Payroll Data'!$B$2)+1),1))+SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Payroll Data'!$A$2:$A$155=$A2,IF('Payroll Data'!$J$2:$J$155="APP2",IF('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155<>"",MATCH("~"&'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155,'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155&"",0)))),ROW('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155)-ROW('Payroll Data'!$B$2)+1),1))+SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Payroll Data'!$A$2:$A$155=$A2,IF('Payroll Data'!$J$2:$J$155="APP3",IF('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155<>"",MATCH("~"&'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155,'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155&"",0)))),ROW('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155)-ROW('Payroll Data'!$B$2)+1),1))+SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Payroll Data'!$A$2:$A$155=$A2,IF('Payroll Data'!$J$2:$J$155="APP4",IF('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155<>"",MATCH("~"&'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155,'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155&"",0)))),ROW('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155)-ROW('Payroll Data'!$B$2)+1),1))
```

Comment: You will need to explain your formula.

Comment: The formula looks for the Job ID which is in the A column, then it looks at the Trade which is in the J column. If the Emp ID for the Trade which is in the F column is unique it counts for each of the trades APP1 thru APP4. I also want it to look at the H column which is hours and if see a negative number do not count the Trade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another nested IF should work as long as you add parentheses in the right places. Taking just the first of the 4 parts you can modify to include the H column criteria like this

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Payroll Data'!$A$2:$A$155=$A2,IF('Payroll Data'!$H$2:$H$155<0,IF('Payroll Data'!$J$2:$J$155="APP1",IF('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155<>"",MATCH("~"&'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155,'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155&"",0))))),ROW('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155)-ROW('Payroll Data'!$B$2)+1),1))`

You can do the same for each of the other 4 parts

Of course by splitting `"APP1"`, `"APP2"` etc. in to the 4 formulas your total may count the same **Emp ID** more than once because each of the 4 parts only counts unique *within that part* - is that how you want it to work?

Edit: Based on your comment try this version

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Payroll Data'!$A$2:$A$155=$A2,IF('Payroll Data'!$H$2:$H$155<0,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH('Payroll Data'!$J$2:$J$155,{"APP1","APP2","APP3","APP4"},0)),IF('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155<>"",MATCH("~"&'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155,'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155&"",0))))),ROW('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$155)-ROW('Payroll Data'!$B$2)+1),1))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: I'd rather have it count the APP1-APP4 as an entire group and then based on job number and unique emp id count. It took me a very long time to figure out what I eventually did come up with. I'm not the best when it comes to excel formulas and functions.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer to suggest a formula that will look at APP1-APP4 all in one

Comment: does the {"APP1","APP2","APP3","APP4"} act as an array?

Comment: that suggested formula is working out great thanks. i've already modified it to work counting other criteria. i really appreciate your efforts. can you suggest a site or book that'll be good for learning excel formulas and functions?

Comment: Yes {"APP1","APP2","APP3","APP4"} is an "array constant" - MATCH function will match each value in J2:J155 against that array - if there's a match it returns a number

Comment: I'm sorry to trouble you, I'm trying to modify why formula to count the unique emp id ($F$2:$F$879) with the array constant ($K$2:$K$879)

Comment: =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH('Payroll Data'!$K$2:$K$879,{"LICA","NYCA","NYPLA","RCKCA","WSTCA"},0)),IF('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$879<>"",MATCH("~"&'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$879,'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$879&"",0))),ROW('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$879)-ROW('Payroll Data'!$F$2)+1),1))

Comment: That formula looks OK, what's the problem?

Comment: I thought it was working but when I modified it for this purpose it's returning a result of 4 when going through the data it's actually supposed to be 1 =SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH('Payroll Data'!$K$2:$K$879,{"NYCOE"},0)),IF('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$879<>"",MATCH("~"&'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$879,'Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$879&"",0))),ROW('Payroll Data'!$F$2:$F$879)-ROW('Payroll Data'!$F$2)+1),1))

Comment: Interesting I just did a small sample of data and it's working properly. I'll have to check the data sheet carefully and see what's going on.

Comment: There really is only one value, just did a Find All for NYCOE

Comment: Is there a way i can get what it's counting to highlight or bold just so I can see what it's doing or do like a step by step calculation so I can see what it's counting?

Comment: Is there a maximum number of rows that you can have, it seems that when the data is above 819 it doesn't calculate correctly. Anything under 819 it calculates properly.

Comment: There should be no maximum value except that implied by the formula - if you have a 878 row range then obviously there can't be more than 878 different values in one column - other than that there's no restriction